# Nullpointer when trying to find a string by ID

Tags: android, findviewbyid

I'm using the below code to find a resource by `id`;

```
setContentView(R.layout.golders);
    for (int i=1; i<hm.size()+1;i++)
        {
            int id = getStringIdentifier("Bus"+i);
            view = (TextView)findViewById(id);
            view.setText(hm.get(i).toString());
        }
```

My `getStringIdentifier()` is working but when I try to set the text I'm getting a `NullPointerException`.

I've used the `setContentView` to focus on the `golders.xml` file which has the `id`s that I want to update.

I've tried Cleaning the project but that hasn't done anything either, any ideas?! Thanks!

EDIT:

```
public int getStringIdentifier(String aString)
    {
        String packageName = "com.example.bustimetable.Robbos";
        int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(aString, "string", packageName);
        return resId;
      }
```

Comment: Can we see the code of `getStringIdentifier`? You said it's working, but `view` would not be `null` if it was working properly.

Comment: It returns a number so I presumed it worked?! SOrry!

Comment: Which line gives you the NPE? Please post the full stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getStringIdentifier(String)` method returns a string ID (something from `R.string`). You need a new method, something like `getIdentifier(String)`, that will return soemthing from `R.id`. I can't see the XML, so I don't know what your `TextView`'s ID is, but... you'll want to verify that the ID is, in fact, `Bus_` where the `_` is some number.

```
public int getIdentifier(String aString)
{
    String packageName = "com.example.bustimetable.Robbos";
    int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(aString, "id", packageName); // Get from R.id, not R.string
    return resId;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `getStringIdentifier()` is returning an id for a string resource. Apparently the id which is returned is not a valid id for a view resource. Even if was, I don't know how you can guarantee that you will get the view that you want. You need to either add another method to return id's for view resources, or modify the one you have so that it will return id's for either string or view resources